# Как правильно пропарсить лабиринт в граф?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, графы

У меня есть лабиринт в двумерном массиве. Как мне правильно его превратить в матрицу смежности, если вершины графа - каждый поворот? Вес ребра - расстояние между двумя вершинами. Его тоже надо получить. Это по сути игровая карта, дорожки из звездочек ограничены решетками - стенами. Мне надо преобразовать это все в граф для использования алгоритма Дейкстры. Отметить перекрестки и повороты отдельно я могу, но было бы лучше, чтобы и это происходило автоматически.

Comment: хотя-бы пример исходных данных в коде покажите, не заставляйте отвечающих с нуля писать

Comment: Правда, покажите вводные данные. Ширина коридора всегда 1? Тупик является поворотом? Должен ли лабиринт иметь края в виде стен?